# Null detection in a complex type with field of another complex type

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, row, plpgsql

I have a complex type with a single field of another complex type:

```
-- Result: IS NULL = FALSE, IS NOT NULL = TRUE
-- Looks OK
CREATE TYPE bar_ok AS (id int);
CREATE TYPE foo_ok AS (val bar_ok);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nulltest_ok()
returns foo_ok as
$$
DECLARE
 _r foo_ok;
 _a bool;
 _b bool;
BEGIN
 _a := _r IS NULL;
 _b := _r IS NOT NULL;
 RAISE NOTICE 'is null %', _a;
 RAISE NOTICE 'is not null %', _b;

 RETURN _r;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM nulltest_ok();

-- RESULT:
-- NOTICE:  is null f
-- NOTICE:  is not null t
```

Complex type with fields of complex and non-complex type:

```
-- Result: IS NULL = FALSE, IS NOT NULL = FALSE
-- Is that OK?
CREATE TYPE bar_bad AS (id int);
CREATE TYPE foo_bad AS (id int, val bar_bad);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nulltest_bad()
returns foo_bad as
$$
DECLARE
 _r foo_bad;
 _a bool;
 _b bool;
BEGIN
 _a := _r IS NULL;
 _b := _r IS NOT NULL;
 RAISE NOTICE 'is null %', _a;
 RAISE NOTICE 'is not null %', _b;

 RETURN _r;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM nulltest_bad();

-- RESULT:
-- NOTICE:  is null f
-- NOTICE:  is not null f
```

1. Is it possible to test null value of complex type with nested complex types?
2. Is it possible to get serialized complex type without "empty" nested complex type?

   ```
   -- Type
   CREATE TYPE some_type AS (
    id int,
    some_complex_type_here bar,
    name varchar
   )
   -- Now - serialized complex type with nested complex type (null):
   (1,(),)
   -- Goal:
   (1,,)
   ```

I am running PostgreSQL 9.4.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit (Windows 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Q1

> 1. Is it possible to test null value of complex type with nested complex types?

You are not the first to be confused by this. For simple types `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` are inverse operations. Either one is true, or the other. But not so for row-valued or composite (complex) types. `IS NOT NULL` only returns `TRUE` if (and only if) every single column is `NOT NULL`. [Per documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html)

> Note: If the expression is row-valued, then `IS NULL` is true when the
>   row expression itself is null or when all the row's fields are null,
>   while `IS NOT NULL` is true when the row expression itself is non-null
>   and all the row's fields are non-null. Because of this behavior, `IS
>   NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` do not always return inverse results for
>   row-valued expressions, i.e., **a row-valued expression that contains
>   both NULL and non-null values will return false for both tests.** This
>   definition conforms to the **SQL standard** [...]

Bold emphasis mine.

***But the complex type was initialized with NULL!***

Well, not *exactly*. composite types are initialized with all nested *elements* NULL, the same is true for nested composite types recursively. And a composite type *containing* a composite type containing *anything* is not considered NULL as a whole. Rather confusing ...

There is a way to get around this: [row-wise comparison](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON) is slightly different from [composite type comparison](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#COMPOSITE-TYPE-COMPARISON). You can **construct a row from the decomposed type** and test with `IS NULL`. This does what you are looking for. [There is an example in the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS)

```
SELECT ROW(table.*) IS NULL FROM table;  -- detect all-null rows
```

Or in your case:

```
SELECT ROW((_r).*) IS NULL;
```

Related:

- [NOT NULL constraint over a set of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021102/not-null-constraint-over-a-set-of-columns/21026085#21026085)
- [Why is IS NOT NULL false when checking a row type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350232/why-is-is-not-null-false-when-checking-a-row-type/27353191#27353191)
- [Delete duplicate rows from table with no unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409184/delete-duplicate-rows-from-table-with-no-unique-key/29410786#29410786)

#### Q2

> 2. Is it possible to get serialized complex type without "empty" nested complex type?

Yes:

```
SELECT '(123,,)'::some_type;
```

Or:

```
SELECT (ROW(123, NULL, NULL))::some_type;
```

**But** as soon as you assign a plpgsql variable of composite type with this, instead of setting the nested composite type NULL as a whole, each nested *element* is set to NULL.

The last function in my test `f_noparens()` demonstrates this. One might argue this is a bug and I wouldn't disagree ...

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c2949/1) with all tests.